# Transforming sequelize promise into observable results to duplicate array

Tags: rxjs, sequelize.js

I have the following code, assuming some Sequelize model `User` with a `findQuery` that is meant to return me a single row:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import sequelize from './database.js'; // Database connection

let sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1";

let searchUser = sequelize.query(sql);
let searchUser$ = from(searchUser);

searchUser$.subscribe(console.log);
```

What I expect it to give me is an `Observable<Array>` that emits a single array with the result in it.

### Problem

It emits to me a single array, with two arrays in it, containing the same value:

```
[
   [ {id: "someid", name: "John", age: 12} ],
   [ {id: "someid", name: "John", age: 12} ]
]
```

### Expected value

```
[ {id: "someid", name: "John", age: 12} ]
```

How do I fix my usage of sequelize such that it returns only one set of results? How do I avoid its duplicate results?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there are duplicate results is because [Sequelize returns both the results of your SQL query and the metadata results](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html). In some cases, the SQL engine you use returns the result as the metadata as well.

What you want to do is to prevent Sequelize from returning to you the metadata.

#### Sequelize Model Usage Reference

> In cases where you don't need to access the metadata you can pass in a query type to tell sequelize how to format the results. For example, for a simple select query you could do:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(users => {
    // We don't need spread here, since only 
    // the results will be returned for select queries
  })
```

#### TL;DR How do I prevent Sequelize from returning the metadata?

Aside from passing whatever parameters you may be binding in your query options, also add the type specifier to your query options:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import sequelize from './database.js'; // Database connection

let sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1";

let queryOptions = { 
    bind: [],
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
}

let searchUser = sequelize.query(sql, queryOptions);
let searchUser$ = from(searchUser);

searchUser$.subscribe(console.log);
```